# Parsing errors with BeautifulSoup4 & Python 3.3

Tags: python, parsing, encoding, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Running this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup (open("my.html"))
print(soup.prettify())
```

Produces this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "soup.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(soup.prettify())
  File "C:\Python33\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u25ba' in position
9001: character maps to <undefined>
```

I then tried:

```
print(soup.encode('UTF-8').prettify())
```

But this fails on account of string formatting with a bytes object:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "soup.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(soup.encode('UTF-8').prettify())
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'prettify'
```

Not sure how to go about solving this. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try to decode the string from bytes first: bytes.decode(my.html)

Comment: I was unable to make this work with beautiful soup (AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your (Windows) console is using `cp437` encoding and there is a character in the soup that isn't supported by that encoding.  The default is to throw an exception in this situation, but you can change it.

```
import sys,io
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.buffer,'cp437','backslashreplace')
soup = BeautifulSoup (open("my.html"))
print(soup.prettify())
```

Alternatively, write the soup to a file and read with an editor that supports the encoding:

```
# On Windows, utf-8-sig will allow the file to be read by Notepad.
with open('out.txt','w',encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
   f.write(soup.prettify())
```